# Functional way of expressing if conditions

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

Consider following situation where a function `verifyRequestBody()` is passed two parameters: `joinPoint` and `verifyRequestBody`. The logic of the function is simple: whenever a function marked with annotation `@VerifyRequestBody` is executed, all its arguments must be validated in certain way (dictated by business logic). There is one catch - the annotation can either be enabled or disabled using the flag `enabled`. I could write following logic in `Kotlin` to achieve this behaviour:

```
    @Before("@annotation(verifyRequestBody")
    fun verifyRequestBody(joinPoint: JoinPoint, verifyRequestBody: VerifyRequestBody) {
        if (!verifyRequestBody.enabled) {
            return
        }
        joinPoint.args
            .filterIsInstance<IVerifiableRequestBody>()
            .map { it.verify() }
            .first { it.hasErrors }
            .let { throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, it.message) }
    }
```

Is there a simpler more functional way of achieving this?

**P.S.** Its not that I dislike using `if` statement - After all I have been using it since I first learnt `BASIC`. Just wanted to see if there is a functional way of doing it in `Kotlin`

Comment: "Simpler," no.  "More functional," yes.

Comment: @LouisWasserman do you know of a "More functional" way? Since I am trying to move from imperative to functional way, any pointer to good learning resource on such things would also help.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be functional at all. You use a function rather as a sub routine, because you are only interested in the effect of throwing an error. In FP effects are encoded as values - of type `Either` in your case. `Either` has a similar effect as throwing by supplying an alternative computional path for the error case. This effectifly short circuits the main computation.

Comment: Thanks @scriptum ! Your response did make me curious and took me to your https://github.com/kongware/scriptum repository which I think I should read. I am just a new comer to the functional paradigm and  would be interested to learn more. Your repository seems to be a good read.